# MySQL behaviour when client disconnects during a query

Tags: mysql, disconnect

Assume that the client issues a long running query that **mutates** the database.
During the query the TCP connection between the client and the server is **closed or interrupted unexpectedly**.

I'd be curious what happens on the server side. Will MySQL rollback the query once it discovers that the client is gone, or it just leaves it as is?

I understand that there may be different behaviours depending on

- query type (transaction or regular query etc)
- MySQL version
- disconnect type (TCP FIN/RST or just the cable is simply unplugged)

Comment: I'd recommend cross posting this on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: MySQL would keep executing INSERT and UPDATE queries so the database files wont be corrupted; SELECT queries will be most likly killed.